# SSRS - filter existing dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that uses parameters. The default parameters are defaulted to contain all available values, so by default the report the contains all possible data.

I want the user to then be able to deselect some of the values in the parameters, and to refresh the charts in the report, so they can drill down to the data that interests them.

But each time the report is refreshed, it runs the query again, slowing down the process.

Is there a way to allow the user to filter the data in the charts, without re-running the query?

I did find this, but it seems that he also didn't get a solution, or I didn't understand how the solution would work.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f905bdb-b8f2-4d9d-ac5b-e85d2f94f0cf/textbox-action-to-filter-existing-dataset-rather-than-rerun-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the query from running again, two high level steps must happen:

1) Make sure that your filters(parameters) are not included in the query. The query needs to be identical, no matter what the user has selected for a filter. This is done by moving the filters into the report. You can set them up as the filter on the tablix or on the row groups that are displaying the data.

2) Set up caching for the dataset. The easiest way to do this is by pulling the data set out of the report and create a "Shared Dataset." when you upload that to SSRS, define the dataset  caching: maybe set it to last an hour. Connect the report to the shared dataset as well.

The full details of this can fill an article, such as http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1919/how-to-enable-caching-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs/ (for an old version of SSRS, but these concepts haven't changed much.)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. In the meantime, I created a static summary table in the database, but cached shared dataset is obviously the better option.